# create Datadog Graph to show my API endpoint hits per second

Tags: python, datadog

I have an API with 10 endpoints(contracts). and i am shipping logs to IIS to data-dog from the API. I also installed data-dog agent on the server.

Now i am trying to create graph for all the endpoint hits per second. there will be only one graph and all the endpoints TPS will be shown on the graph. How can I achieve this? any suggestions?

I tried to create different matrix but not able to achieve this.

I've read that parser file needs to be created.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
 ...
def my_log_parser(logger, test):
metric_name, date, metric_value, extras = line.split('|')
# Convert the iso8601 date into a unix timestamp, assuming the timestamp
# string is in the same timezone as the machine that's parsing it.
date = datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
tags = extras.split(',')
date = time.mktime(date.timetuple())
metric_attributes = {
    'tags': tags,
    'metric_type': 'gauge',
}
return (metric_name, date, metric_value, metric_attributes)
```

Comment: Datadog started offering log management a few months ago. If you really are shipping your logs to Datadog (rather than just parsing them into metrics on the Datadog agent), why not use the "analytics" view of the logs explorer to get this? https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/graph/

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you need to do is create a generic method.

```
Create counter is the metric provided by the dataDog. 
val metric:mutable.Map[String, Counter]
def updateCounter(metricName:String, increment:Int, tags:Map[String, String])={
If(metric.isDefinedAt(metricName)){
//update the existing counter in metric map
}else{
//create the counter and update the metric map
}
}
```

Now when you are hitting the different different end points just call the updateCounter method will will capture your metric with the specific name of your route.

For example you have route like add and subtract
Then call the update counter method with metric name add and subtract.